# full inheritance behaviour with Decorator in php

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, decorator, decorator-chaining

I'm not really used to design pattern generally, and I never used Decorator. I want an object which can have different behaviour according to the context. These behaviours are defined in different classes. I guess Decorator does the trick. But I need that each decorator can access to the same properties, and call children methods first, like with inheritance. So here what I've done:

```
abstract class Component{

    /**
     * Used to access last chain Decorator
     *
     * @var Decorator
     */
    protected $this;

    protected $prop1;//These properies have to be accessed in any decorators

    protected $prop2;

    protected $prop3;

    //this method is used to share properties with the childrens
    public function getAttributesReferencesArray() {
        $attributes=[];
        foreach($this as $attr=>&$val)
                $attributes[$attr]=&$val;
        return $attributes;
    }

}

class Foo extends Component{

    public function __construct() {
        $this->prop1="initialized";
        //...
    }

    public function method1() {//this method can be "overrided" and called here
        //...
    }

    public function method2() {//this method call the overrided or not method1
        //...
        $this->this->method1();
        //...
    }

}

abstract class Decorator extends Component{

    /**
     * Used to access parent component
     *
     * @var Component
     */
    protected $parent;

    public function __construct(Component $parent) {
        $attributes=$parent->getAttributesReferencesArray();
        foreach($attributes as $attr=>&$val)
                $this->{$attr}=&$val;
        $this->parent=$parent;
        $this->this=$this;
    }

    public function __call($method, $args) {
        if(!$this->parent instanceof Decorator &&
            !method_exists($this->parent, $method))
                throw new Exception("Undefined method $method attempt.");
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->parent, $method), $args);
    }

}

class Bar extends Decorator{

    //this method call the component method (I guess Decorator classical way)
    public function method1(){
        //...
        $this->parent->method1();
        $this->prop2="set in Bar";
    }
}

class Baz extends Decorator{

    public function method2(){//this method call the overrided or not method1
        //...
        $this->this->method1();
        //...
    }

}
```

Now we can "construct" the "inheritance" according to the context:

```
//...
$obj=new Foo();
if($context->useBar())
        $obj=new Bar($obj);
if($context->somethingElse())
        $obj=new Baz($obj);
```

and run the object with abstraction of behaviour:

```
$obj->method1();
//...
```

It does what I want, but:

- there isn't anymore encapsulation
- $this->parent is ugly
- $this->this is ugly

What do you think about that?

- How can I access decorator ("children") method another way
- How can I share properties like if they where protected in an inherited context
- Is it a bad usage of Decorator?
- Is there some more elegant pattern that does the trick
- parent and this attributes are a kind of reinventing the wheel isn't it?

**A real world example: the coffee machine**

```
abstract class CoffeeFactory{// Component

    /**
     * Used to access last chain Decorator
     *
     * @var Decorator
     */
    protected $this;

    /**
     * Used to access user choices
     *
     * @var CoffeeMachine
     */
    protected $coffeeMachine;

    protected $water;//the water quantity in cl

    protected $coffeePowder;

    protected $isSpoon=FALSE;

    protected $cup=[];

    //this method is used to share properties with the childrens
    public function getAttributesReferencesArray() {
        $attributes=[];
        foreach($this as $attr=>&$val)
                $attributes[$attr]=&$val;
        return $attributes;
    }

}

class SimpleCoffeeFactory extends CoffeeFactory{//Foo

    public function __construct(CoffeeMachine $coffeeMachine) {
        $this->coffeeMachine=$coffeeMachine;
        $this->water=$coffeeMachine->isEspresso()?10:20;
        $this->coffeePowder=$coffeeMachine->isDouble()?2:1;
        $this->water-=$this->coffeePowder;
        $this->this=$this;
    }

    private function addCoffeePowder(){
        $this->cup["coffeePowder"]=$this->coffeePowder;
    }

    private function addSpoon(){
        if($this->isSpoon)
                $this->cup["spoon"]=1;
    }

    public function isWaterHot($boilingWater){
        return $this->getWaterTemperature($boilingWater)>90;
    }

    private function addWater() {
        $boilingWater=$this->getWaterForBoiling($this->water);
        while(!$this->this->isWaterHot($boilingWater))
                $this->boilWater($boilingWater);
        $this->cup["water"]=$boilingWater;
    }

    public function prepare() {
        $this->addCoffeePowder();
        $this->addSpoon();
    }

    public function getCup() {
        $this->this->prepare();
        $this->addWater();
        return $this->cup;
    }

}

abstract class Decorator extends CoffeeFactory{

    /**
     * Used to access parent component
     *
     * @var Component
     */
    protected $parent;

    public function __construct(Component $parent) {
        $attributes=$parent->getAttributesReferencesArray();
        foreach($attributes as $attr=>&$val)
                $this->{$attr}=&$val;
        $this->parent=$parent;
        $this->this=$this;
    }

    public function __call($method, $args) {
        if(!$this->parent instanceof Decorator &&
            !method_exists($this->parent, $method))
                throw new Exception("Undefined method $method attempt.");
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->parent, $method), $args);
    }
}

class SugarCoffeeFactory extends Decorator{

    protected $sugar;

    public function __construct(Component $parent) {
        parent::__construct($parent);
        $this->sugar=$this->coffeeMachine->howMuchSugar();
        $this->water-=$this->sugar;
        $this->isSpoon=TRUE;
    }

    public function prepare() {
        $this->cup['sugar']=$this->sugar;
        $this->parent->prepare();
    }
}

class MilkCoffeeFactory extends Decorator{

    protected $milk;

    public function __construct(Component $parent) {
        parent::__construct($parent);
        $this->milk=$this->coffeeMachine->howMuchMilk();
        $this->water-=$this->milk;
    }

    public function prepare() {
        $this->parent->prepare();
        $this->cup['milk']=$this->milk;
    }

    public function isWaterHot($boilingWater){
        //The milk is added cold, so the more milk we have, the hotter water have to be.
        return $this->getWaterTemperature($boilingWater)>90+$this->milk;
    }

}

//Now we can "construct" the "inheritance" according to the coffee machine:

//...
$coffeeFactory=new SimpleCoffeeFactory($coffeeMachine);
if($coffeeMachine->wantSugar())
        $coffeeFactory=new SugarCoffeeFactory($coffeeFactory);
if($coffeeMachine->wantMilk())
        $coffeeFactory=new MilkCoffeeFactory($coffeeFactory);

//and get our cup with abstraction of behaviour:

$cupOfCoffee=$coffeeFactory->getCup();
//...
```

Answer (score 2):

The Decorator pattern is not made to do internal changes in the base class (you call this one parent). What you are doing is bad usage of this pattern. The Decorators should only change the output of the functions instead of playing with variables.

One solution is to define getters and setters for your protected variables and to call them from the Decorator.

Another solution is what I prefer personally and that is splitting the behaviour which is dependent on the context and the base class:

```
class Component {
    protected $behaviour;
    function __construct() {
        $this->behaviour = new StandardBehaviour();
    }

    function method1() {
        $this->prop2 = $this->behaviour->getProp2Value();
    }
    function setBehaviour(Behaviour $behaviour) {
        $this->behaviour = $behaviour;
    }
}

abstract class Behaviour {
    abstract function getProp2Value();
}

class StandardBehaviour extends Behaviour {
    function getProp2Value() {
        return 'set by bahaviour ';
    }
}

class BarBehaviour extends StandardBehaviour {
    function getProp2Value() {
        return parent::getProp2Value().' Bar';
    }
}

class BazBehaviour extends BarBehaviour {
    function getProp2Value() {
        return 'set in Baz';
    }
}
```

Now we can use it like this:

```
$obj=new Foo();
if($context->useBar())
    $obj->setBehaviour(new BarBehaviour);
if($context->somethingElse())
    $obj->setBehaviour(new BazBehaviour);
```

I hope this answers your question!

**EDIT after comments**

I see your point that the behaviours replace each other instead of chaining. This is indeed a typical problem for the decorator class. However you really shouldn't change the original class in a decorator class. A decorator class only 'decorates' output of the original. Below a typical example of how the decorator pattern would be used in the real world scenario you mentioned:

```
interface ICoffeeFactory {
    public function produceCoffee();
}

class SimpleCoffeeFactory implements ICoffeeFactory{
    protected $water;//the water quantity in cl

    public function __construct() {
        $this->water=20;
    }

    protected function addCoffeePowder($cup){
        $cup["coffeePowder"]=1;
        return $cup;
    }

    protected function addWater($cup) {
        $cup["water"]=$this->water;
        return $cup;
    }

    public function produceCoffee() {
        $cup = array();
        $cup = $this->addCoffeePowder($cup);
        $cup = $this->addSpoon($cup);
        $cup = $this->addWater($cup);
        return $cup;
    }

}

class EspressoCoffeeFactory extends SimpleCoffeeFactory {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->water=5;
    }

    protected function addCoffeePowder($cup){
        $cup["coffeePowder"]=3;
        return $cup;
    }
}

abstract class Decorator implements ICoffeeFactory {
    function __construct(ICoffeeFactory $machine)
}

class SugarCoffee extends Decorator{
    public function produceCoffee() {
        $cup = $this->factory->produceCoffee();
        if ($cup['water'] > 0)
            $cup['water'] -= 1;

        $cup['spoon']  = TRUE;
        $cup['sugar'] += 1;
        return $cup;
    }
}

class MilkCoffee extends Decorator{
    protected function produceCoffee() {
        $cup = $this->factory->produceCoffee();
        $cup['milk'] = 5;
        return $cup;
    }
}

//Now we can "construct" the "inheritance" according to the coffee machine:

//...
$coffee=new SimpleCoffeeFactory();
if($coffeeMachine->wantSugar())
        $coffee=new SugarCoffee($coffee);
if($coffeeMachine->wantMilk())
        $coffee=new MilkCoffee($coffee);

//and get our cup with abstraction of behaviour:

$cupOfCoffee=$coffee->produceCoffee();
//...
```

Comment: Nice answer ! Mohamed, I see that you're a good engineer, and that you know what you're talking about. I'll try to do a response of the same quality. First off all, your code doesn't work as excepted. When the BazBehaviour is added, $obj forgot the BarBehaviour, which is not what I want. If the context said that Bar need to be used, it need to be even if “somethingElse()”, and that BazBehaviour need to be used too.

Comment: It depends on the getProp2Value() implementation but for exemple, I need that $obj->getProp2Value() can output something like “Set in standard, modified in Bar, modified in Baz” if useBar() and somethingElse(). If useBar() is false but somethingElse() is true: “Set in standard, modified in Baz”. It's maybe not easy to see that with an abstract fooBar example, I'll add a concrete one. After that, I'll comment what you said: “What I'm doing is not a good usage of decorator, I don't respect the encapsulation principle, I should use getter and setter”.

Comment: I will not debate on this subject, but imho, especially in php, getter and setter are evil (you can google that, a lot have been said one this subject). For me, if an object property can be public, protected or private, it make sense that we use it as expected: some properties need to be accessed in all the project, some just by children classes, and some have to be accessed just in the class. Anyway, it doesn't impact the matter. You said Decorator is not the good pattern, which one should I use? Or maybe which combination of pattern?

Comment: Your solution is not strictly a decorator, because a decorator need that behaviours can be added, and in your solution, it can just be changed, the chaining functionality is broken.

Comment: Thanks! I don't encourage you to use setters and getters in thisIn the solution I am not using the Decorator pattern, the pattern used in the code is a form of the Mediator pattern.

Comment: Ok, you said "One solution is", I misunderstood, sorry. For the mediator pattern, that's what I've seen, but mediator isn't decorator, I use it for doing a behaviour abstraction, but decorator is more for adding dynamically a behaviour imho. If you want to edit your answer or add another it will be welcome. I've added a real world example in my question, if it can help to see what I need.

Comment: I now see what you mean. You can see the edits after the **EDIT after comments**.

Comment: Good... We reach now the core problem (+1 for that), but all is not ok. I like the way you're naming the classes (better than mine), and your example have now the fonctionality of adding behaviour (decorator pattern). The problem with your naming, is that "SugarCoffee" (and "MilkCoffee") is not a Coffee, but a "CoffeeFactory", it extends Decorator which implements "ICoffeeFactory". So if you name it SugarCoffeeFactory you have now: `class SugarCoffeeFactory extends Decorator{ public function produceCoffee(){$cup = $this->factory...`

Comment: So you have a decorated factory which have a property $factory, don't you think it's quite similar to $decorated->parent (with another naming style)? Let's focus on the problem now: decorator is not really mandatory, it's just a known way to add behaviour.

Comment: But calling children functions in parent class like classical inheritance (polymorphism) is mandatory. that's why I use `$this->this->someFunc()` in the parent class. Using same properties in child class is not really mandatory, it's more just something more "easy". But for me, using voids getters and setters is quite the same.

Comment: I have edited the "real world example" question, it's now more complex. You'll have now to use the function `addWater()` of `SimpleCoffeeFactory`, in the childrens, it use `isWaterHot()` which is redefined in `MilkCoffeeFactory`. And take a look at my comments on Fu Xu's answer, about the ingredients order in the cup array, the same apply to your example.

Answer (score 2):

Still a bit incomplete but it does basically everything:

1. abstract Component class that everything extends.
2. abstract Decorator class that modifies classes extending Component.

It's a lot of code so here's the pastebin link:

[Old] http://pastebin.com/mz4WKEzD

[New] http://pastebin.com/i7xpYuLe

**Components**

1. Can extend one another
2. Can modify / add / remove properties
3. Can share properties with decorators

**Decorators**

1. Can attatch functions to components
2. Can modify / add / remove component properties

**Example Input**

```
$Sugar = 1;
$DoubleSugar = 1;

$Cofee = new SimpleCofee();
$Tea   = new SimpleTea();

$Cofee->Produce();
$Tea->Produce();

print "\n============\n\n";

if($Sugar)
{
    new SugarCube($Cofee);
    $Cofee->Produce();
    new SugarCube($Cofee);
    $Cofee->Produce();
}

if($DoubleSugar)
{
    new SugarCube($Tea);
    $Tea->Produce();
    new SugarCube($Tea);
    $Tea->Produce();
}
```

**OutPut**

```
Making coffee....
Adding Water: 150
Making cofee: array (
  'cofeee' => 25,
)
Making tea....
Adding Water: 150
Making tea: array (
  'tea' => 25,
)

============

Making coffee....
Adding sugar: 1
Adding Water: 140
Making cofee: array (
  'cofeee' => 25,
  'Spoon' => 1,
)
Making coffee....
Adding sugar: 1
Adding sugar: 1
Adding Water: 120
Making cofee: array (
  'cofeee' => 25,
  'Spoon' => 1,
)
Making tea....
Adding sugar: 2
Adding Water: 130
Making tea: array (
  'tea' => 25,
  'Spoon' => 1,
)
Making tea....
Adding sugar: 2
Adding sugar: 2
Adding Water: 90
Making tea: array (
  'tea' => 25,
  'Spoon' => 1,
)
```

**UPDATE**

That was crazy but now children can overload parent functions. On top of that you can now use array interface `$this['var']` to access shared properties. Hashes will be added automatically and transparently.

The only downside is that parents have to allow functions to be overloaded.

**NEW Output**

```
Making Cofee....
Adding Water: 150
Making Cofee: array (
  'cofeee' => 25,
)
Making Tea....
Adding Water: 150
Making Tea: array (
  'tea' => 25,
)

============

Making Cofee....
Adding sugar: 1
Adding Water: 140
Making Cofee: array (
  'cofeee' => 25,
  'Spoon' => 1,
)
Making Cofee....
Adding sugar: 1
Adding sugar: 1
Adding Water: 120
Making Cofee: array (
  'cofeee' => 25,
  'Spoon' => 1,
)

I have take over Produce!
But I'm a nice guy so I'll call my parent

Making Tea....
Adding sugar: 2
Adding Water: 130
Making Tea: array (
  'tea' => 25,
  'Spoon' => 1,
)

I have take over Produce!
But I'm a nice guy so I'll call my parent

Making Tea....
Adding sugar: 2
Adding sugar: 2
Adding Water: 90
Making Tea: array (
  'tea' => 25,
  'Spoon' => 1,
)

============

DoubleSugarCube::SuperChain(array (
  0 => 'test',
))
SugarCube::SuperChain(array (
  0 => 'DoubleSugarCube',
))
SimpleTea::SuperChain(array (
  0 => 'SugarCube',
))
SimpleCofee::SuperChain(array (
  0 => 'SimpleTea',
))
```

**UPDATE**

This is my final draft. I can't keep changing my solution bit by bit. If there is something wrong state it all in a list.

Removed callparent and put all functionality of it into `parent::function`

1. Children have access to parents properties.
2. Children can overload parent functions.
3. Overloading will start at base class all the way up till `abstract class Decorator` class. Afterwards the properties / methods are obtained from parent passed to constructor.
4. You said you liked your method of property sharing. So I haven't bothered to answer that.

I hope you'll accept the answer now. If not then I look forward to yours. I hope when you sort everything out you will share it with the rest of us.

Cheers

Comment: I have to say... Wow! mAsT3RpEE, you arrive here, 17h before the end of the bounty, and you understood a good part of the problem, and give a smart solution on the first answer. For that, +1. But... (Yes there is a "but", and not only one) I prefer my solution for sharing properties (your solution work I guess, but for me the hash way is not really beautiful). A child cannot replace his parent methods, and just call his direct parent ones without calling other chained-decorators ones.

Comment: You use `->parent` (and I guess, if you want to solve the problem "A child cannot replace his parent methods", `->this`) which I wanted to avoid. More generally, your code is not clean and you'll need a lot of Xtra code in the decorators. But if you can improve that, you'll win the +50. But I'm not satisfied, you are just the one who have done the bests efforts.

Comment: If you don't have time to improve all, just focus on the methods (the properties is not mandatory), and if you can fiund a solution for `$this->parent` and `$this->this` (replaced with `parent::` and `$this`), your answer will be the accepted one.

Comment: @Pierre About the `$hash`? This is important. The hash makes it impossible for a child class to access the parents properties. Either it must rehash the parent class or use the data hash value. I put it there specifically for my own reason.

Comment: @Pierre I will make the hashing automatic. so you can use $this['coffee'] instead of $this[$hash.'coffee']. Also note. Children can only override parent properties **if they are defined**. Otherwise only a local copy of the property is added (this also done on purpose). If you want decorators to share properties you will have to pass the decorator instead of the parent class.

Comment: you're right, I make a sort of framework. I see how you want to do with the overloaded functions, but ask you that question: what happens if a parent call `this->myFunc()` with  myFunc overloaded. The parent function will be called, no? What about polymorphism? And it will add extra code in child function in order to reuse overloaded one... I look forward to reading your updated code.

Comment: It's nice, but the child doesn't call his parent's `addSugar()` but his own twice. There's a problem on the function inheritance, but I guess your solution best fit my needs, so you've earn the +50. Enjoy it! keep in mind that your answer isn't the accepted one yet, if you want to work with me a bit more, it could be...

Comment: if I were your friend, I would have said that the +50 is enough, but I would have paid a beer, because I don't need anything back to enjoy a beer with a friend.

Comment: for the parent::, it would have been nice, but I'm not sure that it's possible to overload a basic php functionality with a callstatic. But if you find something, consider that your answer is the accepted one.

Comment: you could always use the normal parent:: to access members of inherited classes. That would mean creating a callparent function that checks for the func in both `$this->parent` and `parent::`. With that I think everything would be complete?

Comment: @Pierre added function `CallParent` that calls parent:: if not then the parent class which then calls parent:: until eventually there are no parents and it all fails. You should compile these in c and extend php on your server.

Comment: It sounds good to me, but I guess `__call()` will be better than `__callStatic` for doing that. In that magic func, we need to check wich class is calling (maybe with `get_called_class()`?) and compare it with `$this->parent`. Why not? It should be tested... What about a parent calling an overloaded func? It's a main feature.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your comment. You know, I think we shouldn't add code like `CallParent`or `$this->parent` or all that stuff, because it's bad for reusability. We should reuse (bypass?) language construction instead. Compiling in c is not an option, because the app have to be setup easily.

Comment: I understand you can't change your solution bit by bit, and explaining you why it's not ok will take me a lot of comments. So I'll create a unit test with all wanted features, and test all solutions, and publish results and comment these results. If you want to continue to work with me, we could use that as a base, and make it evolving progressively. I know I'm very demanding, and that can be annoying, but I guess you also love well done job. The project is intended to be open source, and you'll be informed when I'll publish it.

Answer (score 1):

there is a solution to fit the coffeemachine problem

```
abstract class Coffee { 
    protected $cup = array();
    public function getCup() {
        return $this->cup;
    } 
}   
class SimpleCoffee extends Coffee {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->cup['coffeePowder'] = 1;
        $this->cup['water']        = 20;
        $this->cup['spoon']        = FALSE;
    }
}

abstract class Decorator extends Coffee { 
    private $_handler = null;

    public function __construct($handler) {
        $this->_handler = $handler;
        $this->cup      = $handler->cup;
    }
}

class SugarCoffee extends Decorator {
    public function __construct($handler) {
        parent::__construct($handler);
        $this->cup['water'] -= 1;
        $this->cup['sugar']  = 1;
        $this->cup['spoon']  = TRUE;
    }
}
class MilkCoffee extends Decorator{
    public function __construct($handler) {
        parent::__construct($handler);
        $this->cup['water'] -= 5;
        $this->cup['milk']    = 5;
    }
}

$wantSugar = TRUE;
$wantMilk  = TRUE;

$coffee = new SimpleCoffee();
if($wantSugar)
    $coffee = new SugarCoffee($coffee);
if($wantMilk)
    $coffee = new MilkCoffee($coffee);

$cupOfCoffee = $coffee->getCup();

var_dump($cupOfCoffee);
```

and there is another `real world example`, I hope it can help you:

```
abstract class MessageBoardHandler {
    public function __construct(){}
    abstract public function filter($msg);
}
class MessageBoard extends MessageBoardHandler {
    public function filter($msg) {
        return "added in messageBoard|".$msg;
    }
}
class MessageBoardDecorator extends MessageBoardHandler {
    private $_handler = null;
    public function __construct($handler) {
        parent::__construct(); 
        $this->_handler = $handler;
    }
    public function filter($msg) {
        return $this->_handler->filter($msg);
    } 
}
class HtmlFilter extends MessageBoardDecorator {
    public function __construct($handler) {
        parent::__construct($handler);
    } 
    public function filter($msg) {
        return "added in html filter|".parent::filter($msg);
    }   
}   
class SensitiveFilter extends MessageBoardDecorator {
    public function __construct($handler) {
        parent::__construct($handler);
    }   
    public function filter($msg) {
        return "added in sensitive filter|".parent::filter($msg);
    }   
}
$html      = TRUE;
$sencitive = TRUE;
$obj = new MessageBoard();
if($html) {
    $obj = new SensitiveFilter($obj);
}
if($sencitive) {
    $obj = new HtmlFilter($obj);
}
echo $obj->filter("message");
```

Comment: Because it breaks the decorator-chaining. It's ok for the first of the chain (the one I called "Foo"), which will be always instanciated, but for the others (Bar, Baz, etc), the chain of inheritance have to be programaticaly defined, according to the context. If you hardcode like that (is it really what you meant?): `class Baz extends Bar{...` it becomes a classical "static" inheritance. Anyway, thank you for answering, if you want to edit or to add a new answer, it will be welcome.

Comment: I updated the sourcecode. I don't know if it is what you want.

Comment: Yes! It's more something like that. But you said that the decorator-chaining is not broken, and it is. The abstraction of behaviour is something I want, but not only. I want that according to the context, the object can be always a component, sometimes a Foo, sometimes a Bar (what you've done) and sometimes a Foo AND a Bar (with Bar "extends" Foo, what you have not done). I enjoy your efforts, continue.

Comment: oh. I know. so you do not need a abstract class `Component`. but an instance of `Component` before it is turned to be an instance of a sub class of `Component` ?

Comment: Yes you're right, it's a way to do that, the one I chosed, the classical way to do that, the decorator pattern way. With this pattern, Component is abstract because you can define abstract functions (not implemented) that must be defined in sub class. But it's not mandatory in my example (because there is always a foo instance), and I think you've well understood what I want to do. The goal is only to do a kind of dynamic inheritance. Have you seen my "real world example" (the cofee machine), in the question? It can maybe help you to understand what I want. You could read Mohamed response too.

Comment: oh, sorry. I didn't noticed there is a `real world example` added in the question. and I have updated my source to solve the `real world example` problem.

Comment: Your coffe machine works because it's a simple example. But consider now that it's less easy, that ingredients order is important. To follow the example, to prepare your cup of coffee, you need to put the coffee powder first, sugar if needed, and the spoon the milk and the water. You can't remove water in the cup after, because it's mixed with the coffee, sugar and milk. That's what you're doing: you prepare a simple coffee cup, with 1cl of coffee powder, 20cl of water. You need sugar so you remove 1cl of water (mixed with coffee) and you add the sugar and the spoon.

Comment: The sugar will be on top of the coffee, but it should be added before in order to be more mixed, if the spoon is a plastic one, it's possible that it fall out of the cup, that's why coffee machine put spoon before water. After that you remove 5cl of water (mixed with the sugar and the coffee) and add 5cl of milk. Your example is not ok, consider the function addWater() as if it was a complex one, defined in SimpleCoffee, and that you doesn't want to redefine it in SugarCoffee and in MilkCoffe. I will update my "real world example" in order to take that into account.

Comment: I have edited the "real world example" question, it's now more complex. You'll have now to use the function `addWater()` of `SimpleCoffeeFactory`, in the childrens, it use `isWaterHot()` which is redefined in `MilkCoffeeFactory`.

Comment: I have studied Mohamed's response, and I think maybe he is right. Decorator is not a good pattern here. In your `really world example`, maybe we can define another Class `Cup` to handle all activities. and all you added to be more complex is not the key problem. may be I can implement my solution tomorrow.

Comment: I'm sure that Decorator is the best solution, it's just the best I find. How can you handle adding behaviour without? But I'm ok if you give me a better solution. If you create a class cup, I guess you're just moving the problem. It will be a super class, and each time I want to add a new functionality, I'll have to change this class. Or maybe you want another decorator on `Cup`? You said that complexity is not the key problem, but I think it is. You can manage the example because it's too simple, but I needed the decorator for complex problems.

Comment: And don't forget what the problem is, it's in the question title: full inheritance behaviour with Decorator in php. Or in other words: dynamical inheritance, or adding behaviours but keeping a way to handle old ones (with the possibility to access future ones). I think Mohamed and you make the same error, you hardcode a new solution each time I add complexity, but if I continue to do that, your solutions will become monsters. Please take into account the single responsibility principle.